# How to start Fuseki server when we have already existing database?

Tags: jena, fuseki, tdb

I have Fuseki TDB database having size 53MB. I try to make it available on an endpoint by the command line utility `./fuseki-server --tdb2 --loc=/path/to/database /ds` . The endpoint on `localhost:3030` get started but on querying, it gives empty results. I would ask if anyone can help.

Comment: Check that /path/to/database points to the top of the existing TDB2 area, not within it.

Comment: i tried like that as well. One thing more, I need to extract the whole data out of the database as nt or ttl, file, so if you can tell me how to do it. I tried the backup command but it returned .nq file, which can not be uploaded to Virtuoso. So if you can point me the solution please

Comment: Let me guess. The NQ file wasn't empty. Your query problem could be because is that the query was about the default graph and you only have named graphs in the data. `SELECT  * { GRAPH ?g {}}` and maybe "--set tdb:unionDefaultGraph=true" or better for the long term usage, write a config file. If the data has named graphs, you can't use a single-graph-only format to get the data out although you can use a CONSTRUCT query to get a graph.

Comment: thanks a lot. By using the argument "--set .." you mentioned, with the ./fuseki-server command, it worked successfully ...Once again thanks